# Update local file dependency with npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a project with a local file dependency in my `package.json` like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "dep_1": "file:../../dep_1"
  }
}
```

When I do `npm install` it is installed into node_modules. But if I make changes to `dep_1` how do I update the module version in node_modules?

I tried doing `npm update` but nothing happens.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using a relatively new version of npm (*I used version 2.14.2*) you can bump the version number in package.json and `npm update dep_1` should work. Otherwise how can npm know that something needs to be updated?

**Note:** This will only work if the version is higher than what has previously been installed. You will have to clean the cache to reset this behaviour.

However, you can forceably (and lazily) update local modules by simply running `npm install` again. e.g.

```
npm install dep_1
```

It should be fast since its on your local computer and you don't have to play around with version numbers.

For more detail see the discussion about this issue on the official npm repository page: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7426

Comment: Actually doing `npm install dep_1` doesn't work. Because `dep_1` isn't in the npm repository. But doing `npm install ../../dep_1` works perfectly.

Comment: @SeanLynch : ```npm install dep_1``` works for me here. I have npm version 2.14.2 and my line contains ```"dep_1" : "file:../dep_1"```

Comment: @SeanLynch : Also, did you try bumping version and running ```npm update```

Comment: I am using npm version 2.11.3. I tried to do a version bump and then doing the update but the behavior was the same.

Comment: @SeanLynch : Well, in any case, if I was developing locally I would probably stick with ```npm install``` update method since you don't have to go messing with your version. Also, maybe you should update your npm version to something newer. Bumping the version and using ```npm update``` works for me and more importantly, answers the question . I will update my answer to note that it may not work on older versions of npm.