# NPM update and outdated with local paths using file:

Tags: javascript, npm, lerna, monorepo

Running `npm update --depth=9999` or `npm outdated --depth=9999` skips [local path](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) dependencies.

I assumed they would act as any other published packages.

We run commands from the root of monorepo:

```
@org/
  app/
    package.json
package.json
package-lock.json
```

```
package.json

"dependencies": {
  "@org/app": "file:@org/app"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "prettier": "^1.16.3",
}
```

```
@org/app/package.json

"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.8.0"
}
```

Also, when running `npm outdated` from sub-package dir, NPM does not use root `node_modules`.

```
Package                Current   Wanted   Latest  Location
react                  MISSING   16.8.0   16.8.1  @org/app
```

I've found similar questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618876/5590570), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873867/update-local-file-dependency-with-npm)

- running `npm i` is not a solution since we're using `package-lock`
- I want to keep dependencies in sub-packages, not in root `package.json`

Am I doing something wrong, or it is not supported at the moment and should just use something like [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check)?

`npm-check` can not update sub-dependencies, so to make a complete update of the whole dependency tree we need to:

- `rm package-lock`
- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `npm cache clean`
- change versions by hand in root and sub-packages
- `npm i`
- commit new `package-lock`

Is this correct or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update local file dependency with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873867/update-local-file-dependency-with-npm)