# How to update an NPM package installed with file://?

Tags: npm

I have a local package installed with `file:` like this:

```json
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "foo": "file:../foo"
    }
}
```

And I want to update it with `npm update foo`, after I have updated that module, but turn out nothing happened. How can I update package installed through `file:` with `npm`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update local file dependency with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873867/update-local-file-dependency-with-npm)

Answer (score 0):

Update your file :)
or change `file:...` -> version (example) `^4.1.1`

Comment: I am not publishing my module therefore I have to use `file:...` to install it. For update my file, which one are you referring to?